# Libserial Package, debain

Tags: linux, debian, libraries, packages, serial

I'm looking for the Libserial (the C++ RS232 Library)
in debain but i cant find it.
am i getting the name wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how you add it.
this method involcves buildign it from the source files.
open you command line (bascially anyware)

type the following commands (wait fro eact to compete before adding the next)

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libserial/libserial/libserial-0.5.2/libserial-0.5.2.tar.gz?use_mirror=waix

tar -xf libserial-0.5.2.tar.gz
cd libserial-0.5.2
./configure
make
make install
cd ..
rm libserial-0.5.2.tar.gz
rm -d libserial-0.5.2
```

Comment: having compiling problems.

Comment: I followed this answer and had to fix minor compiling issues (some include headers were missing). Then it compiled and seems to work

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude search serial` turns up some ruby packages on my lenny machine, but nothing for c++. You may have to build from the tarbal.

Comment: I know that it doesn't turn up, i did search already